# onActivityResult not called when using Lollipop activity transitions

Tags: android, android-transitions

In the onCreate method of my HomeActivity I check if the user is logged in and if he is not, LoginActivity is started. If I start LoginActivity without transitions by using:

```
startActivityForResult(intentLogin, INTENT_REQUEST_LOGIN);
```

everything is fine, onActivityResult gets called as planned when I call finish() in the LoginActivity. But if I use:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
startActivityForResult(intentLogin, INTENT_REQUEST_LOGIN, activityOptionsCompat.toBundle());
```

and respectively call ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition() in LoginActivity, onActivityResult never gets called in HomeActivity.

Transitions in LoginActivty are set as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (Utils.isRunningLollipopAndHigher()) {
        setActivityTransition();
    }
    ...
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setActivityTransition() {
    Transition transitionEnter = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    transitionEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    transitionEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(transitionEnter);
}
```

I finish LoginActivity with:

```
private void finishLogin() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);
}
```

The transitions itself work perfectly. Any pointers what could be the issue with onActivityResult?

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok, after running some tests it seems like starting an activity with transitions and forResult during an activity lifecycle method always leads to onActivityResult not being called. If I start the LoginActivity e.g. after a button press, everything works as expected.

Comment: How you are setting result intent from your successor activity?

Comment: I just set "setResult(RESULT_OK);" when login was successful. I do not need to send back any other data, so I am not setting an intent.

Comment: Are you finishing the activity?

Comment: If you can update that code too then it will be easy?

Comment: Yes, I finish the activity: setResult(RESULT_OK);
        ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I fully understand your comment, what do you mean by "update that code too then it will be easy?"

Comment: Can you update your code of successor activity which is being called for result or the Activity which you are setting `setResult(ReSULT_OK)`.